# Rails 3: routing to customer areas

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing

I'm a Rails 3 beginner, but have experiences with other MVC web frameworks and need a starting hint about how to setup my routing in Rails. The application should allow users to register and after that the users data should be available at URLs like:

http://domainname/username/xyz

The common and user independent part should be available at

http://domainname/abc

To distinguis between both routes, I would force usernames to have at least 6 characters and all "abc"-routes will have 5 or less. Until this point I would be manage the routing by myself, but for the "xyz" part of the user area I would like to use the existing REST full features of rails. Any hint how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you already read http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html?

It's really a good resource for this sort of question. I believe some of the scheme you describe falls into the "Non-Resourceful" routing category.

Comment: Yes, I read the guide, but it didn't helped my. I think I need something like scopes, but the name of the scope must be dynamic. I also unterstand non-resourceful routing. But as I wrote, I would like to combine both.

Comment: Rails routes to the first match, AFAIK. So you could put your 'abc' and similar routes before your username route, which becomes a catchall. I think the pieces of the puzzle are in the Guide.