# Insert xml element as first child using ElementTree in python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using python to create an element in an xml document and then insert it as the FIRST CHILD of the document.  So, if I were creating an elment named `newChild` I would want xml like this...

```
<root>
  <childA></childA>
  <childB></childB>
  <childC></childC>
</root>
```

to become...

```
<root>
  <newChild></newChild>
  <childA></childA>
  <childB></childB>
  <childC></childC>
</root>
```

I know that the order of elements in arbitrary xml shouldn't matter, but I writing xml doc for an ancient system which breaks if xml elements aren't in the expected order, so I don't have a choice in that regard.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's your concrete problem? What's the error message? Or do you expect us to write your code?

Comment: The definition of my problem is very concise.  I did read the doc (and admitingly missed the proper answer on the first time through) - I hadn't coded anything yet because I hadn't found anything in the docs which suited my needs.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739834/rails-3-routing-to-customer-areas

When you asked that question, did you expect someone to write your code?  What was your error message?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.insert](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.insert) method allows you to add a new sub-element to an element inserted at a specific position.

In your case `element.insert(0, new_sub_element)` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you - that looks exactly like what I was looking for.  I'm used to perl parsers which use copy/paste and didn't think to look for an insert method.  I'll give it a shot when I'm back at work on Monday and upvote/accept.

Comment: On my Python 2.7 runtime, insert replaces the existing component at that position.
In this example, childA would be replaced by newChild